# Meteor methods don't work on Modulus server

Tags: node.js, meteor

I had an app deployed on Meteor's servers and it worked as expected.

Now, I've moved the app to a NodeJS platform, called [Modulus](https://modulus.io/), using their CLI tool. (App hosted at http://crazygain.com)

For some reason, the method calls - `Meteor.call` or `Meteor.apply` - are not executed. Looking at the network indicator in Chrome Dev Tools I saw that the request is never sent.

I tried sending requests directly from the console, and got the same result.

e.g. when I execute the following

```
Meteor.call("foo",function(){console.log("callback");});
```

on the new Modulus server I simply get `undefined`

However, when I run it on the old Meteor server I get the "callback" log as expected.

I'm quite puzzled and unsure what can cause such behaviour.

UPDATE:

`meteor.status()` returns

`Object {status: "connected", connected: true, retryCount: 0}`

Answer (score 1):

This might be because the web socket connection isn't established. Meteor calls & subscriptions depend on the DDP protocol which have a separate connection to the server.

Have a look at `Meteor.status()` to see if you are connected & if not investigate your connection's web socket/long polling connection.

It might just be a connection issue. Your meteor call works for me with the site you have provided.

Comment: meteor.status() returns connected

Comment: on this domain - http://crazygain-10266.onmodulus.net? For me it only works on the old domain (crazygain.com)

Comment: Now I'm really puzzled... Thx

Comment: As it turns out the problem is local and occurs only with my Wi-Fi, presumably because it uses a static IP

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the [Meteor deployment guide on Modulus' website?](http://blog.modulus.io/deploying-meteor-apps-on-modulus) You need to convert the app using demeteorizer.

Comment: I have used their designated CLI tool which includes "demeteorizing" the app